# How to extend and customize ember-charts

Tags: ember-charts

I am using ember-charts component. In that component am using timeSeries graph.

How can I customize,extend the legends,hover effects?

Answer (score 0):

This question isn't specific enough for a very good answer, but generally:

Documentation is available at http://addepar.github.io/ember-charts/#/ember-charts/documentation, some things can be configured in this way.

If you're hoping to change the appearance of a chart, you can typically just write CSS that will apply to the chart. Use your browser's debugging tools to find the part of the chart you want to configure, or look at https://github.com/Addepar/ember-charts/blob/master/src/css/ember-charts.less to get an idea of what might be configurable.

Comment: Hi @azirbel,what am required is, I want to extend the legends instead of overriding in their ember-charts.js file itself.. Example: In ember-charts they are having drawLegend method. In that method, they are highlighting the hovered label data in chart UI. Here, they are autogenerating the labels based on the given data. Instead of their auto generation process.. I would like to customize in my manner. Hope you understood..